# Remove / change the white border from the CARTO map

Tags: carto

I published a CARTO map that I need to embed in WordPress.

Can I either remove the white border or change it to a black one?

Here's the map: 
https://colossalmedia.carto.com/builder/31f83b6e-9ef6-46dc-bc28-c7a1419eccf2/embed

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to remove the white border from an embed BUILDER map at this moment.